# How to solve Oracle ORA-00904 Invalid identifier on Union where columns are from different datatypes

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, type-conversion, union

I have a query that results in single column with CLOB containing JSON object

```
select json_object( key 'casinos' VALUE                     

                      (select json_arrayagg(

                                     json_object(
                                              key 'code' VALUE cas.code, /*error invalid identifier*/
                                              key 'name' VALUE cas.name,
                                              key 'skins' VALUE  coalesce (

                                               (SELECT json_arrayagg( 


                                                json_object( key 'code' VALUE csk.code,
                                                             key 'name' VALUE csk.name

                                                             )
                                                         )              
                                                  from CASINO.CASINOCLIENTSKINS csk 
                                                  WHERE csk.casinocode = cas.code
                                                  ), '[]') 
                                                FORMAT JSON    )
                          from   ( SELECT to_char(cas.code), cas.name FROM CASINO.CASINOS cas
                                    UNION all SELECT 'default', 'Default casino' FROM DUAL
                                            ) cas
                                     ) returning clob
                     ) responseJson
FROM DUAL
```

need to add dummy record, but cas.code column is from NUMBER datatype, dummy column is VARCHAR. Converting  cas.code to char results in ORA-00904 Invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `SELECT` statement you have `TO_CHAR(....)` but you didn't give it an alias. That `SELECT` does not output any column called `CODE`.

The solution is simple: `SELECT TO_CHAR(CAS.CODE)` **`AS CODE`**`, .......`

**EDIT**

After you do that, you will get another error, "Invalid number". That will be from the join condition

```
WHERE csk.casinocode = cas.code
```

because `casinocode` is **number** data type and `cas.code` is **varchar2**. Now `cas.code` has one value, the string `'default'`, which can't be converted implicitly to a number.

The solution is to wrap `csk.casinocode` within `to_char()` also, in this condition.

**Question** for you though. Since you are performing this join after you added the "default" row, and it's an inner join, the "default" row will be discarded by the join. So, why are you adding it at all?

You probably want an **outer** join there.

As a general strategy - you shouldn't try to debug your code when it's already wrapped within the JSON stuff. You aren't even getting your desired results as the output of a standard SQL query - fix that first, get it 100% right, and then wrap the results within JSON operators.

Comment: mathguy,using your suggestion now ends with ORA-01722L invalid number

Comment: @NikolayMarinov - I think I see where that may be coming from. Adding to the answer.

Comment: WHERE to_char(csk.casinocode) = to_char(cas.code) did the trick and the result I need

Comment: @NikolayMarinov = you shouldn't need TO_CHAR on the right-hand side, since that is already a "character" data type (you already applied TO_CHAR in the subquery).

Comment: @NikolayMarinov - also, did you really get the desired result? Did you actually get the "default row" into the JSON, without altering the join?

Comment: @methguy, yes I'm getting the CLOB with proper JSON object inside